# AWS changing the folder name omitting $ sign if there are double $

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, urlencode

I upload photos to an AWS S3 bucket. I created a unique file name like:

"NJGB$$5Wz/d494fb8d-824a-48bc-99d7-25451f0aac30.jpg"

When upload is finished, I can retrieve the same key with my aws bucket.

But when I go to that folder, I see that "NJGB$$5Wz" became "NJGB$5Wz".

UPDATE: If I encode the key, it becomes: NJGB%24%245Wz and S3 creates a folder with the same name. But, If I get link to that folder from AWS console, it encodes again and it became NJGB%2524%25245Wz

Do you think it is a bug? How can I fix that?

Comment: How did you upload the file? If it was via the CLI, can you provide exactly the command as you entered it? In Linux, $$ refers to the current process ID, which might have impacted things. Also, how do you "go to that folder" -- via the CLI, or via the web S3 Management Console?

Comment: Sorry to not mention that. I am using AngularJS-Javascript library to upload files to S3

Comment: And how are you viewing the contents of the folder, where you see only one dollar symbol?

Comment: If there is only 1 dollar symbol, everything is good.

Comment: You said *"But when I go to that folder, I see that "NJGB$$5Wz" became "NJGB$5Wz""*. Where did you see this? In the console? Or from a command-line?

Comment: I copied a file to an Amazon S3 bucket using that name and it worked fine for me. (Mac Chrome)

Comment: It didn't omit one of dollar sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of how an object appears in the Amazon S3 Management Console, the `key` (filename) of the object is the Source of Truth.

Try accessing the bucket via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). The `aws s3 ls s3://BUCKETNAME` command will show you the keys of all objects (divided into common prefixes, that behave like folders).

If there is a mismatch between the console and an API/CLI call, then the console is wrong. Feel free to use the **Feedback** button in the console to report any strange behaviours in the browser. You could also try another browser and see whether the problem persists.